# setTimeout(x, 0) not delaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a web page with a form on it; I want to warn the user if they move away. I haven't implemented dirty checking so my `onbeforeunload` code is simply

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'message'
};
```

I don't want this warning when they *submit* the form, so I remove the event on submit. However, the submit may *fail*, so I need to put the event back afterwards (so if they *then* navigate away they still get warned). To that end I have done the following:

```
var tempDisableBeforeUnload = function() {
    var obu = window.onbeforeunload;
    if (obu) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = obu;
        }, 0);
    }
}
$("form.noWarnOnSubmit").submit(tempDisableBeforeUnload);
```

This works fine in Firefox and IE - the `setTimeout(x, 0)` defers the restoration of the event handler until *after the `submit` has decided whether it is successful or not*.

However, in Chrome, the timeout appears to occur immediately, and I get the warning when I submit my form.

How can I make this work on Chrome, or how else can I achieve the end of "don't warn on submit, but put the warning back if the submit fails"?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by whether the submit was successful?  Do you mean potentially other event handlers calling `preventDefault` etc?

Comment: It does work in Chrome: http://jsbin.com/bavayuwohu/3/edit . At least for me (v39).

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I have unobtrusive validation running and that potentially cancels the submit.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel I wonder if there's a race condition of some kind. I don't use Chrome away from work to test but I wonder what would happen if you added another submit handler with a 1s delay - and whether the outcome would depend on the order in which they were bound.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel [like this](http://jsbin.com/qudigicele/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Rawling Looks like you are right. In your example, for the first button, I'm getting the `onbeforeunload` warning.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you do the following:

```
var unloadActive = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(unloadActive) return 'message'
};
$("form.noWarnOnSubmit").submit(function(event){
    unloadActive = false;
    // do all your checks and things, whatever, and if the checks fail:
    unloadActive = true;
});
```

Then you don't need to do all that function juggling which might cause issues. I haven't tested this, but this is how I would do it.

Comment: Unfortunately all my checks and things are bound onto the submit event already by other code... but you're right, I could potentially unbind them and call them manually in my own submit handler. But then I have to make sure that my binding is called *after* all the other bindings so I can make sure I get them all...

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome my immediate issue by

- Binding my event to fire after the jQuery validation event, by deferring my `submit` event binding:

```
$(function() {
    $("form.noWarnOnSubmit").submit(disableBeforeUnloadIfNotCancelled);
});
```

- Changing my event handler to only unbind the `onbeforeunload` event if the `submit` event is cancelled.

```
var disableBeforeUnloadIfNotCancelled = function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dislike this solution because it relies on the order in which scripts are loaded, so I'm going to leave this question open for other solutions.